# What is the best method for importing data?

Tags: importing-exporting

I have various spreadsheets of data to import into Drupal 8. I can create a content type for each spreadsheet. I can convert the data the spreadsheets into various formats (csv, JSON, XML, whatever). What I can't work out is what is the best way to import the data. I only need to do this one time. What is the best method?

Comment: Note that the Feeds module is no longer being ported to D8...

Comment: Reference for above statement: https://www.drupal.org/node/2604358 (as it is not on the module page)